# How to show the login screen instead of the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screen

I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and being idle to trigger

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

(goes to login screen)

instead of lock screen I intend to replace every event where lockscreen would appear to show login screen(but still logged in)

how do I do it?

Comment: I have 12.04 TLS according to my help file

Comment: This remains an issue in 18.04.  Now we have to close out the lock screen just to get to the login form.  Uggh.

Answer (score 2):

### To create the shortcut

- Go to the Settings Manager from the menu.
- Go to Keyboard.
- In the Application Shortcuts tab press on Add.
- Enter `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` then press OK.
- Press the desired hotkey.

### To run a command after 2 idle minutes

- Create a bash script, containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The target may depend on your system. i8042 is mouse and keyboard on mine.
log=/proc/interrupts
target=i8042

measure_activity() 
{ 
    count=$1
    interrupts_start=`grep $target $log | awk '{ print $2 }'`
    interrupts_stop=`sleep 1 && grep $target $log | awk '{ print $2 }'`

    if [ "$interrupts_start" == "$interrupts_stop" ] ; then
        ((count++))
        if [ $count -eq 120 ] ; then
            dm-tool switch-to-greeter
            measure_activity 0
        else
            measure_activity $count
        fi
    else
        measure_activity
    fi
}

measure_activity 0 &
```

- Make it executable.
- Add it to Application Autostart tab of Session and Startup.

P.S.: I've got the script from [here](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=26447) and I edited it for you.

Comment: thank you this part works, but I also want to go to `greeter` after being idle for 2 minutes or so.

Comment: You're right. I didn't see the second part of the question the first time I read it. Now I hope that my answer is complete.

Comment: For me it goes to greeter regardless of me moving the mouse or not.. I guess it is because target is not i8042 for me

Comment: Open `/proc/interrupts`, move the mouse then open it again. Compare the two logs. The last column is the input, you want to change instead of i8042. Figure out which row you need. It must have different values between the two logs in the first column to be the row, corresponding to mouse movements. It should be one of the "usb" ones.