# 14.04 Lockscreen show all users

Tags: lock-screen

In 14.04, When I have an active session and lock screen via shortcut super-l, or Gear->"lock/switch account", the lock screen only shows my user with password.

To login as someone else, (my 5 year old likes to play minecraft while I am away), you have to click on the Gear->("Switch Account..." or a specific user) to be shown a list of users to login as.

Is there any way to change the default behavior so that when I lock screen, it goes right to the list of users, rather than only my user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://askubuntu.com/questions/412145/how-to-show-the-login-screen-instead-of-the-lock-screen?rq=1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/412145/how-to-show-the-login-screen-instead-of-the-lock-screen?rq=1)         you might also look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42166/how-to-make-the-lock-screen-look-like-the-login-screen?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user list and then you can switch user on the login screen.
Please read this carefully and try to reverse the process http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/lightdm-how-to-disable-user-list-or.html

Sorry, I cant find matched scenario. This is the close one..